# Excel Date formulas stopped updating

Tags: excel

I have formulas in an excel doc that rely on the =Today() function to update the file daily. Recently these formulas stopped updating even though the workbook is still on auto calculate. If I click the calculate sheet button, nothing happens. I can only update the cells by clicking in them then hitting enter, or by repasting the formulas. All of the affected cells have a data type of general. This is the second workbook to have this issue. How can I fix the bug?

Comment: Is it *only* `=TODAY()` formulas acting this way, or all formulas?

Comment: Write a macro which is applied to the sheet you want to update such that any time that specific sheet is opened, you rewrite the formula `=TODAY()` in the desired cell.

Comment: @BruceWaye its just the today() function

Comment: @e.traguer, that is a good idea. But before I make the update, I would like to know what is triggering the bug. Otherwise I will have to update every file that used the function

Comment: @Katie good point.  It is an odd bug

Comment: Does it recalculate if you close and open the workbook?  Does it recalculate if you enter any formula someplace else on the worksheet?

Comment: Double check that the sheet is set to Auto Calculate (File > Options > Formulas > Workbook Calculation > Automatic).  See if pressing `F9` updates the formula, as well.

Comment: Double checked. Its set to auto calculate and every formula without a time function is working as expected. F9 and entering a formula elsewhere have no affect. The cells are only updated by hitting enter while in the cell or doing a copy/paste.

Comment: Is it doing this in just two specific workbooks? Or *all* workbooks, even a new one you create, save, close, and re-open?  Perhaps too, you can post the literal formula you're using?  It it just `=Today()` or is it a formula that has `Today()` in it?

Comment: Just the two, and both are workbooks that went months with no changes and no issues before the formula broke. One of the affected cells just has =today()